# ResultSetMetaData-GetRows of the result

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I made the following query to my database so that I can return the columns that a table has

```
String searchStatement = "SELECT\n" +
        "   table_name,\n" +
        "   column_name,\n" +
        "   data_type\n" +
        "FROM\n" +
        "   information_schema.columns\n" +
        "WHERE\n" +
        "   table_name = '" + tableName + "';";

ResultSet columnsRs;
Statement s = connection.createStatement();
columnsRs = s.executeQuery(searchStatement);
ResultSetMetaData md = columnsRs.getMetaData();
```

Now I need to have access to the rows of the result. How can I do it?

[image]

For example, in the following row I could I store the COLUMN_NAME in a variable?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to do. On the one hand, you ask how to access **the rows** of the result (which you'd do through `columnRs`), but on the other hand you're asking how to store a column name in a variable (you retrieve the name from `md`). Those are two separate things.

Comment: Sorry,my bad. I want to have access to all the rows. Only then I want to go through them

Comment: @MarkRotteveel basically, I want to get access to all the columns. Then go through them and store its name in a variable

Comment: Do you mean [`ResultSetMetaData.getColumnLabel`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnLabel(int))? If not, you need to be more explicit with what you're asking, because either you didn't read the javadoc which would make this clear, or you want something more complex than that.